# Question about select query (Access)

Tags: ms-access

Example:

I have 2 tables: country and users

> **COUNTRY:**   ID (integer) | name (text)
>
> 1 | Spain
>
> 2 | France
>
> 3 | UK
>
> **USERS:** IDu (integer) | username (text)
>
> 12 | Pepe
>
> 14 | Mary

I want to return all rows of both tables using a same query. Is possible?

Separately will:

```
Select * from country

Select username from users where IDu=12
```

**I WANT TO RETURN**:

**ID / NAME / USERNAME**

1 | Spain | Pepe

2 | France | Pepe

3 | UK | Pepe

Comment: You might like to look up Cartesian Join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be creating a Cartesian join where no JOIN between the two tables...

```
select country.id, country.name, users.username
   from users, country
   where users.IDu = 12
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast and useful reply!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return all combinations of the two tables:

```
ID | NAME | USERNAME
 1 | Spain | Pepe
 2 | France | Pepe
 3 | UK | Pepe
 1 | Spain | Mary
 2 | France | Mary
 3 | UK | Mary
```

use:

```
SELECT country.* 
     , users.username 
  FROM country
     , users
```

Comment: Idem. Thank you for your fast and useful reply! :-)